# How to get the date value like '2015/28/07 15:00:00' without using Dateadd and DateDiff function in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @MyDate1 DATETIME='2014/04/28 15:15:15'; return   
DATE(@MyDate1.day,@MyDate1.Month, @MyDate1.year, @MyDate1.hour)
```

I need output like `'2014/04/28 15:00:00'`, Without Using `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` Functions.

Thanks

Comment: So, you want round the time down to the hour?

Comment: if you do not need minutes and seconds then truncate it and add :00:00 at the end

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Looks like MS SQL Server?

Comment: If you use MSSQL then try: `select CAST(REPLACE(@MyDate1, right(@MyDate1, 5), '00:00') as smalldatetime)`

Comment: Yes,Microsoft SQL Server. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: "The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"............................................................    This Message Will shown when i RUN this query ..@MegaTron

Answer (score 2):

If on SQL Server 2012+ there's also the [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function that is very flexible:

```
-- note that the datetime literal is not in the unambiguous ISO8601 format 
-- so the conversion to datetime might fail on other languages than English 
-- it would work if declared as the datetime2 type.
DECLARE @MyDate1 DATETIME = '2014/04/28 15:15:15';    

SELECT FORMAT(@MyDate1,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:00:00');

Result: 2014/04/28 15:00:00
```

The result can be treated as a datetime if you need to do further processing, so for example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,FORMAT(@MyDate1,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00'),GETDATE());
```

would return 16.

Comment: That is not an unambiguous format for representing datetimes. Your example fails with `set language Italian`

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, probably for a lot other languages too (like German). Although it fails on the `DECLARE @MyDate1 DATETIME = '2014-04-28 15:15:15';` line, so it's not the format function that fails but the conversion of the string literal to a datetime value.

Comment: Ah I hadn't noticed that you switched from `'yyyy/MM/dd HH:00:00` to `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00'`. Probably because your text indicates that this is the "result" of the previous stage.

Comment: @MartinSmith It doesn't make any difference, `'2014-04-28 15:15:15'` still fails on Italian. It's missing the `T` separator that would make it ISO8601.

Comment: If you cast to `datetime2` rather than getting the implicit cast to `datetime` that `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format will work fine for all language/datetime settings. - `SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,CAST(FORMAT(@MyDate1,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00') AS DATETIME2),GETDATE());
`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 2012+

```
DECLARE @MyDate1 DATETIME='20140428 15:15:15';

SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@MyDate1), 
                         MONTH(@MyDate1), 
                           DAY(@MyDate1), 
                DATEPART(HOUR, @MyDate1), 
                                       0, 
                                       0, 
                                       0)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try following query:-

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE('2014/04/28 15:15:15'), ' ', HOUR('2014/04/28 15:15:15'),':00:00') as New_format
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I apologize. DATE() is a mysql function.